# Extract data (likes) from JSON API using Python

Tags: python, json, facebook, pull

I want to pull the number of likes for my project.

Here's my code:

```
import facepy
from facepy import GraphAPI
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
access = 'CAACEdEose0cBAE3IL99IreDeAfqaVZBOje8ZCqIhf6tPaf7HsPF3J9DYRWi3YuSTf0HXQwr2LMAgczDBWBSDNFzHrEjxzkBQ9hbZCYC1fB2z1qyHs5BeAZCV3zyU8JhEcbSiiB5Bf73gZAfQ1rUa2pdx9U24dUZCX0qMDzvXHLHV9jPRiZBByB2b2uEHGk22M4ZD'
graph = GraphAPI(access)
page_id= 'walkers'
datas= graph.get(page_id+'/', page=True, retry=5)
for data in datas:
    print data
```

And here's the output:

```
  {
    u'category': u'Product/Service',
    u'username': u'walkers',
    u'about': u"Welcome to the home of Walkers Crisps. When it comes to making Brits smile, we\u2019ve got it in the bag (yeah, we went there.) We're here Mon-Fri, 9am-6pm!",
    u'talking_about_count': 3076,
    u'description': u'To find out more about Walkers, visit:\nhttp://twitter.com/walkers_crisps\nhttp://www.youtube.com/walkerscrisps',
    u'has_added_app': False,
    u'can_post': True,
    u'cover': {
      u'source': u'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/t31.0-8/s720x720/11165156_10153204315777649_4115137634691483959_o.jpg',
      u'cover_id': u'10153204315777649',
      u'offset_x': 0,
      u'offset_y': 0,
      u'id': u'10153204315777649'
    },
    u'name': u'Walkers',
    u'website': u'http://www.walkers.co.uk',
    u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/walkers',
    u'likes': 552762,
    u'parking': {
      u'street': 0,
      u'lot': 0,
      u'valet': 0
    },
    u'is_community_page': False,
    u'were_here_count': 0,
    u'checkins': 0,
    u'id': u'53198517648',
    u'is_published': True
  }
```

I want to pull the number of likes, preferably just the number. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: JSON data is a dictionary here, so should just be: likes = datas['likes']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a generator, there's no *good* way to get a specific element.
You can either iterate over it and check for each element if it's the one you're looking for, or, if you will need more than one element from it, convert it into a dictionary.

This is one way to convert it:

```
new_dictionary = {}
for name, value in datas:
    new_dictionary[name] = value
```

With this you could then get likes with:

```
likes = new_dictionary['likes']
```

Or if you only want to get 'items' from it:

```
for name, value in datas:
    if name == 'likes':
        likes = value
```

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. My code looked like this:

Comment: Okay. Print out just datas and look how that looks. Might be that datas is an array containing a dictionary.

Comment: Hmmm I still get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test 19999.py", line 9, in <module>
    likes = datas['likes']
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Oh, it's a generator. Try converting it to a dict first: tempdata= {d.name:d.value for d in datas}, then you can try calling it with likes = tempdata['likes']

Comment: Hmm tried that and got this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Hm, you could try datas.get('likes') as well, but I suspect it wont work.

Comment: I have updated my answer with something that should actually work.

Answer (score -1):

```
import facepy
from facepy import GraphAPI    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import json

access = 'CAACEdEose0cBAE3IL99IreDeAfqaVZBOje8ZCqIhf6tPaf7HsPF3J9DYRWi3YuSTf0HXQwr2LMAgczDBWBSDNFzHrEjxzkBQ9hbZCYC1fB2z1qyHs5BeAZCV3zyU8JhEcbSiiB5Bf73gZAfQ1rUa2pdx9U24dUZCX0qMDzvXHLHV9jPRiZBByB2b2uEHGk22M4ZD'

graph = GraphAPI(access)

page_id= 'walkers'

datas= graph.get(page_id+'/', page=True, retry=5)

likes = datas['likes']

print likes
```