# Extracting specific information from a generator object

Tags: python, json

This question has been asked ([Extract data (likes) from JSON API using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782942/extract-data-likes-from-json-api-using-python)), but I cannot get their answer to work. In particular, I want to print out just certain fields in the output I have.

As is detailed in the original question the data are in the following format (JSON-like), but are actually a "generator object."

```
 {
    u'category': u'Product/Service',
    u'username': u'walkers',
    u'about': u"Welcome to the home of Walkers Crisps. When it comes to making Brits smile, we\u2019ve got it in the bag (yeah, we went there.) We're here Mon-Fri, 9am-6pm!",
    u'talking_about_count': 3076,
    u'description': u'To find out more about Walkers, visit:\nhttp://twitter.com/walkers_crisps\nhttp://www.youtube.com/walkerscrisps',
    u'has_added_app': False,
    u'can_post': True,
    u'cover': {
      u'source': u'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/t31.0-8/s720x720/11165156_10153204315777649_4115137634691483959_o.jpg',
      u'cover_id': u'10153204315777649',
      u'offset_x': 0,
      u'offset_y': 0,
      u'id': u'10153204315777649'
    },
    u'name': u'Walkers',
    u'website': u'http://www.walkers.co.uk',
    u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/walkers',
    u'likes': 552762,
    u'parking': {
      u'street': 0,
      u'lot': 0,
      u'valet': 0
    },
    u'is_community_page': False,
    u'were_here_count': 0,
    u'checkins': 0,
    u'id': u'53198517648',
    u'is_published': True
  }
```

As such, to extract specific fields (e.g., "likes"), we need to use a loop like suggested in the original answer:

```
new_dictionary = {}
for name, value in datas:
    new_dictionary[name] = value
```

However, when I try to use the code they suggested, I get the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack." I understand what the error means, but I'm not sure how to fix it in this situation.

Comment: the generator doesn't return pairs.

Comment: would you mind showing the output of `print(datas)`?

Comment: Certainly: <generator object paginate at 0x00000000036823A8>.

Comment: mhh sorry, how about `print(list(datas))`

Comment: That is the same output as above but enclosed on either side: [{u'category':...]